# Essbase Error 1241109 Unable to Open file

Tags: hyperion, essbase

I am automating the process to run a report script. The batch script is located on Windows and the Essbase server is on UNIX.

Getting an error while executing the below statement

> export database App.DB using server_file 'Report1.rep' to data_file '/apps/AppName/FileName.txt';
>
> TIA

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

is the path correct?
Essbase does not create directories, so maybe /apps/Appname does not exist.
I would also suggest to put the Files under Appname/Database but thats a personal thing.